# How to convert Flash actionscript background to transparent?

Tags: flash, actionscript, background, transparent

HI help me solving this issue. I want to change the background to transaprent. currently its in black color. you can find the code from below link.

http://pastebin.com/dK5rgCTA

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transparent background is html related
use the param

Warning wmode tranparent is processor intensive, you shall always find a way to not use it.
For example you can embed your html background in your swf.

Answer (score 0):

To set the SWF to transparent,Check your flash object html properties.

```
                      <object classid="00" width="600" height="450">
                      <param name="movie" 
                      <param name="quality" value="high">
                      <param name="wmode" value="direct" > // here change
```

Setting the bg colour of your flash file will be ignored if you set the wmode =transparent.
If you run the .swf as inside the player externally the background color will be shown.